# Member type (nested class) as a template parameter

Tags: c++

I have a lot of boilerplate classes of the form:

```
struct Foo1 {
    using Self = Foo1;

    template <typename TYPE>
    using Refl = TYPE::SubClass1;
};

struct Foo2 {
    using Self = Foo2;

    template <typename TYPE>
    using Refl = TYPE::SubClass2;
};
```

(Where `SubClassX` is usually a nested class, but it can also be a type alias)

Is it possible to generate them using a template? Something like

```
template <???>
struct Foo {
    using Self = Foo;

    template <typename TYPE>
    using Refl = TYPE::???;
};
```

So I could use this like `Foo<SubClass1>`, and this should create an equivalent class to `Foo1`. Of course, `Foo<SubClass1>` is not a syntax that C++ allows. Is there some kind of trick to make something like this possible?

Comment: Not with templates, since the name is dependent on the scope of `TYPE`. You could hack it with C-style macros, but that's quite a messy approach.

Comment: This can be done with reflection: https://godbolt.org/z/5bhqYrYdh but unfortunately that's not coming to major C++ compilers anytime soon

Comment: @Artyer: thanks for the work, it's interesting to see this solution. Hopefully there will be a way to simplify your solution, I think it's too complex for what it does. https://wg21.link/P2662R3 with constexpr for loops should make it simpler when they will become available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with template, as you want to be generic from a **name**.

With some (boilerplate) type traits, you might do

```
template <template <typename> class SubClassTrait>
struct FooT {
    using Self = FooT;

    template <typename TYPE>
    using Refl = typename SubClassTrait<TYPE>::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct SubClassTrait1 {
  using type = typename T::SubClass1;
};
template <typename T>
struct SubClassTrait2 {
  using type = typename T::SubClass2;
};

using Foo1 = FooT<SubClassTrait1>;
using Foo2 = FooT<SubClassTrait2>;
```

Alternatively, there is still MACRO which can do the job:

```
#define defineFoo(ClassName, SubClassName) \
struct ClassName {                   \
    using Self = ClassName;          \
                                     \
    template <typename TYPE>         \
    using Refl = TYPE::SubClassName; \
}
```

with usage

```
defineFoo(Foo1, SubClass1);
defineFoo(Foo2, SubClass2);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing new classes, but I suppose this problem cannot be solved without that, so I'm going to accept your answer.